# Plot sector-cutted data with conditional plotting (Gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot

I have data that depicts a 3D distribution of points caracterizing a star. So in short words, I have a random 3D distribution of points inside a sphere. I want to do a 3D plot of all the points except all of them that are within the x>=0,y>=0,z>=0 sector. That is I want to cut out 1/8 of the sphere. My attempt:

```
spl 'data' u ($2>=0.?($3>=0.?($4>=0.?1/0:$2):$2):$2):3:4:7 w d lc palette z
```

does nothing. I mean, it seems to plot everything. Columns are $2=x, $3=y, $4=z and $7 a magnitude to give the color to the points.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your filter looks Ok to me.  maybe try `lc palette cb` instead of `lc palette z`?

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional syntax at least seems correct.  With the following data file:

```
1 1 1 1
1 -1 1 2
1 1 -1 3
1 -1 -1 4

-1 1 1 5
-1 -1 1 6
-1 1 -1 7
-1 -1 -1 8
```

The command

```
spl 'data.dat' u ($1>=0.?($2>=0.?($3>=0.?1/0:$1):$1):$1):2:3:4 w points pt 7 ps 3 palette z
```

produces this output:
[image]

The point at (1,1,1) is absent, as it should be.  This is using gnuplot 4.6.0.  When I tried the command `w d lc palette z` I couldn't see anything, perhaps the `with dots` option behaves differently?

Comment: `w dots lc palette z` also works.  The dots are just so small that they're really hard to see with your datafile.  +1 for coming up with good test-data/demonstration though.